# Iphone: uitextview setting done button

Tags: iphone

I use a UITextView in my application. The text editing is ok. I set the return button to Done.
When I finish the editing, I like to hide the keyboard with the done button.
My Question: How can I set the done button?

Thanks,
Balu.

Comment: The questions seams unclear. You can set the type of the button at the lower right of the keyboard via UITextFields returnKeyType property. But I think that is not what your wanted to ask.

Comment: So, I open a text file and the full of contents give up to the textview. Now I editing and When I finish I push the Return key (Done). I think The textview better for this application than the textfield. Question: How can I also defines the default Return process. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set your controller as the textField's Delegate, implement UITextField Delegate method textFieldShouldReturn in your controller and resign first responder before returning TRUE/YES:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```